# Php form. Need help to send it when validate

Tags: php, html

Let's start to say I'm still new to this php. I'm not going to give up, I will learn it. I have a problem whit my form code, that I have put together. I can't get it to send it, after it have validate all my inputs fields. Can not understand why. Maybe I can get some help? Maybe you can fix it so it works? So I have something to work with.

```
<?php
// This is your email address
$to = "my@mail.com"; 

// Subject title
$subject = 'Testing work now pls';

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";

// If press send
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    // If not empty
    $errors = array(
                    $errorsname = $errorsemail
                    );

    // Start validation

    // Check if name not empty
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $errorsname = "You must write their name.";
    } else {
        $name = ($_POST["name"]);
        // Check if only letters in name
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z æøå-ÆØÅ]*$/",$name)) {
            $errorsname = "Their name only content letters."; 
        }
        // Check if name to short
        if(strlen($_POST['name']) < 2 )
            {
                $errorsname = 'Their name is too short.'; }
        // Check if name to long name
        if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 30 )
            {
                $errorsname = 'Their name is too long'; }
    }

    // Check email
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $errorsemail = "You must enter their email."; }
    else {
        $email = ($_POST["email"]);
        // Check if e-mail address syntax is valid
        if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
            $errorsemail = "Invalid email address."; }
    }

    // Check errors if non continue
    if (empty($errors))
        {

            // Make message ready
            $message = "
    Stupid just work pls! $navn, $email
    ";

            // Then send mail

            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

            // Redirect to sucesse page
            header('Location: mysite.php');
        }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
.errors {
    color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hmmm....Help?</h2>
<span class="errors"><?php echo $errormessage; ?></span>
<form name="kontakt" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Deres navn.." value="<?php echo $name;?>">
<span class="errors"><?php echo $errorsname;?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Din e-mail.." value="<?php echo $email;?>">
<span class="errors"><?php echo $errorsemail;?></span>
<br><br>
<br><br> 
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: basic debugging: did you check the return value of `mail()`? if it's FALSE, then you've got a mail configuration error. For anything else, did you check the mail server's logs to see what happened after PHP handed over the email?

Comment: Please post your server error logs, so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: Yes as mentioned above, have you performed basic debugging to see where script execution varies from what you expect to happen?

Comment: You're explicitly setting a value for $errors, then checking later to see if it's empty() before sending mail. $errors will never be empty, so the mail won't be sent.

Comment: Sorry I did not respond fast back. Okay I see. I say thank you very much for your time and help. Now, I need try your good advice. To gets this to work. Must look at the responses I received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a multitude of issues here. Firstly in your HTML you need to check to see if your error variables are set, if so, display them, otherwise you are going to get php errors:

```
<span class="errors"><?php
            if (isset($errormessage)) {
                echo $errormessage;
            }
            ?></span>
        <form name="kontakt" method="post" action="<?php echo                 htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
            Name: <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Deres navn.." value="<?php
            if (isset($name)) {
                echo $name;
            }
            ?>">
            <span class="errors"><?php
                if (isset($errorsname)) {
                    echo $errorsname;
                }
            ?></span>
            <br><br>
            E-mail: <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Din e-mail.." value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            <span class="errors"><?php if (isset($errorsemail)) {
                    echo $errorsemail;
                }
            ?></span>
```

Secondly, as states above, your $erros array should be instantiated similar or as Barmar has shown.

and lastly, your $email variable is not instantiated when loading the page, you're going to have to give it a default:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];}
else{
$email = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$errors` to a non-empty array before you do the validation, so

```
if (empty($errors))
```

will always fail. You should initialize it as:

```
$errors = array();
```

Then your validation code should add to it in this way:

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name'] = "You must write their name.";
}
```

and

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors['email'] = "You must enter their email.";
}
```